# Ludwig Sylow 12 december 1832

Tags: math-history, sylow-theory

Not a question, but just to commemorate that [Ludwig Sylow](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Biographies/Sylow.html) was born today exactly 181 years ago, on 12-12-1832. Note that $1832=2^3.229$, and hence by Sylow's theorems there is no simple group of order $1832$.

Comment: Maybe it's more appropriate to post this in meta, but anyway it's nice reminder.

Comment: Yes your are perfectly right but in meta we cannot tag "Sylow-Theory" - I tried to put it in meta in the first place. Maybe it warrants a separate tag "History of Mathematics" or something.

Comment: Ah! - there is in fact such a tag. I added the tag!

Comment: I think there exist a tag called "celebrations" in meta in case you didn't find it.